# Qual é a função do método ismount

Tags: python, python-3.x, sistema-de-arquivos

Encontrei umas funções do modulo `os` e do seu submodulo `path` que não estou a ver o que possam fazer:

1. *islink*
2. *ismount*

Podem existir links no file system?

Answer (score 5):

Podem sim. Links (*hard* ou simbólicos) aparecem na maioria dos sistemas operacionais e sistemas de arquivo.

- No Linux você pode criar um link com o comando [ln](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln).
- Em versões modernas do Windows você criar um link com o comando `mklink`, em versões antigas (XP ou inferior) você pode fazer isso com o comando `junction`.

Da mesma forma, a maioria dos sistemas operacionais te permite montar partições (veja o comando [`mount`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_mount.htm) do linux).

Os métodos `islink` e `ismount` do módulo [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) verificam se determinado caminho representa um link simbólico ou uma partição montada.

Answer (score 3):

`islink` diz se o caminho especificado é uma [**ligação simbólica**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liga%C3%A7%C3%A3o_simb%C3%B3lica) (*symbolic link*, *soft link* ou *symlink*). Antigamente esse tipo de caminho só existia em sistemas *NIX, mas as versões recentes do Windows também dão suporte a eles. Grosso modo, eles funcionam como um "apelido": se um arquivo está em `/caminho/pro/arquivo` e existe um link simbólico `/meu/link` associado a `/caminho` então você pode chegar ao mesmo arquivo através de `/meu/link/pro/arquivo`.

(Alem dos links simbólicos existem também os [*hard links*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) - que funcionam de forma semelhante mas possuem representação interna diferente. Sugiro abrir uma pergunta específica caso queira saber mais sobre esses tipos de link)

Já `ismount` diz se o caminho especificado é um ponto de [montagem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29). Um exemplo no Windows seria o `C:\` (ou `D:\`, etc). No *NIX, um caminho é um ponto de montagem caso o caminho "pai" esteja em um dispositivo diferente do caminho filho. Ex.: em `/media/cdrom/arquivo` o arquivo está no CD, mas o caminho `/media` está no próprio SO, então `/media/cdrom` é um ponto de montagem.